# Creating a class for a classification tree with python

Tags: python, dataset, bigdata

I’m working on a big data project using python for my university.
I’m using this dataset ( https://www.kaggle.com/carolzhangdc/imdb-5000-movie-dataset) from Kaggle. The final aim is to create a classification tree. So now, I’m stuck on how to create a class in one variable (for example imbd score) that I can call 0 if the variable is less than 70 and call the class 1 if the variable in higher than 70.

Comment: Add a column to your data-set and use that column as an attribute for your class or create a function in the class that can perform the same calculation

Comment: Hi, thanks! anyway I tried and I put this code                                                           

def return_score(self):
    if newmovieDef["IMDB Score"] < 8:
        return 0
    return 1

newmovieDef["Return Score"]= newmovieDef["IMDB Score"].apply(return_score)

Comment: and it gives me this error       ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Use the a.any() or loop thru the values in the column...hope this helps!
If you share a code sample I may be able to help more